# Python PIL: font weight and style

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library, truetype

On my computer I have only one file for Ubuntu Condensed font, it seems. Namely:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf
```

However, in LibreOffice I can make this font bold and italic: 
[image]

On [Ubuntu font tester](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/) web page I can also set different font weights (namely, regular and bold) and different font styles (namely, normal and italic) for the Ubuntu Condensed family. In CSS this might translate to:

```
/* CSS for bold and italic Ubuntu Condensed font */
font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 700;
```

Or:

```
/* CSS for regular and normal Ubuntu Condensed font */
font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
```

However, when it comes to Python's PIL/Pillow, I couldn't find any working option in [ImageFont](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html) that would modify the font's style and/or weight other than load different font files with `ImageFont.truetype()` function.

For the "regular" Ubuntu font (not Condensed) I could load one of the four separate files to get normal, bold, italic and bold+italic styles in Python:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-RI.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-BI.ttf
```

But not for Ubuntu Condensed.

So the question is, is it possible to draw an image with bold and/or italic Ubuntu Condensed font in PIL/Pillow? Or is it possible, at least, to generate four Ubuntu Condensed files, so that it can be used like the Ubuntu font from Python?

Comment: Have you already tried the `ImageFont` module? It has `load()` and `TrueType()` functions that might be useful here. (Edit: here's the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html)!)

Comment: @ladygremlin, I probably did. But I still don't see how to provide one file `Ubuntu-C.ttf` for Ubuntu Condensed and then choose style that I want (like, italic or normal). There seems to be no options for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can select the font-variant you want using the method `set_variation_by_name`.

In order to get all the variants use the method `get_variation_names` which should give you a list of names.

```
>>> from PIL import ImageFont
>>> 
>>> font = ImageFont.truetype(...)
>>> font.get_variation_names()
[b'Normal', b'Bold', b'Italic', b'Bold, Italic']
>>> font.set_variation_by_name('Italic')
```

This should give you the desired font variant.

Comment: Could you show the `import` statement so folks can see where you get those functions from please?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I couldn't make it work so far: I get `File "/userhome/34/amakukha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 497, in get_variation_names
    names = self.font.getvarnames()
OSError: invalid argument` on Ubuntu with Pillow 6.2.0. Similar error on MacOS with Pillow 7.1.1.

Comment: That is weird. Can you at least use the method `font.get_variation_axes()` to find out how the font can be changed?

Comment: @AndriyMakukha this would allow yout too use the method `font.set_variation_by_axes(...)` as documented here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.set_variation_by_axes.

Comment: No, same error: `File "/userhome/34/amakukha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 527, in get_variation_axes
    axes = self.font.getvaraxes()
OSError: invalid argument` on Ubuntu with Pillow 6.2.0.

Comment: According to the docs, `OSError` is raised if the font is not a "variation font", i.e., the font file contains only one variant. If other variants are available elsewhere, they are likely stored in separate files. For example, on Windows, the Arial font has separate files for regular, bold, italic, bold and italic, etc.